# In python, is it possible to list of the functions within a module if module name is a variable?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm working on a small app that can list all functions and help documents from given module name and function name. Just practice my `tkinter` skill.

After I created and entrybox, and get the input from user as module name and import it by using some code like this:

```
module_name = module_entry.get()
__import__(module_name)
```

Then I am trying to list all function names by using:
`function_list = dir(module_name)`.
But I found `dir()` function must apply directly to the module name after importing them, eg: `dir(pandas)`, or `dir(matplotlib)`. is there any work around method to list all the functions when module name is a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__import__` returns the module from the name, so just do

```
module_name = module_entry.get()
module = __import__(module_name)
dir(module)
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution:) I didn't know that.